# Does this series converge or diverge? Which test could be used?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

How would you prove or disprove that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}(n+1)}{n^2}$$
converges?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It is a real number. Asking question in such a way of yours, desires such answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write $$\frac{(-1)^n(n+1)}{n^2}=(-1)^n(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})$$
so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{1}{n^2} $$

The first series converges (but does not converge absolutely) by Leibniz's alternating series theorem. The second series converges absolutely (it is well-known), so it converges.

Answer (score 1):

Take $$u_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}(n+1)}{n^2}, \;\;v_n=\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}.$$ Then $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}u_n/v_n=1.$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}v_n$ converges, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n$ also converges.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the [Alternating Series Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx):

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{n^2}$$

One of the easiest conditions to test for is the if the $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

Then you can see that that condition is true:
$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{n+1}{n^2}=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}n}{n} \ \text{then by direct substitution:}$
$$L=\frac{1+0}{\infty}=0$$

The second condition that one has to test for is if the sequence is monotonically decreasing. Using the derivative test to determine if the test is decreasing:

> $$f'(n)\le 0$$
>   Then one can use the sequence as a function here $f(n)= \frac{n+1}{n^2}$, and then taking the derivative of that function gives you $f'(n)=\frac{-n-2}{n^3}$ Because $f'(n)\le0 \ \forall \ n\ge 1$ We know that the function is decreasing, therefore the series is converges.